# SVG element, JQuery, Javascript. mousedown event not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

Looking at the code on http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_svg.htm

Trying to run:

```
document.addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
    var elem = event.target || event.srcElement; console.log(elem);
});
```

or:

```
$('body').mousedown(function(event) { 
   var elem = event.target || event.srcElement; 
   console.log(elem); 
});
```

Neither event handler fires when I click on any of the SVG images on the page. Somehow it seems that Javascript/Jquery does not recognise SVG images.

Anyone come across this before?

Thanks

EDIT: OK so this is a problem with the SVG being in an iframe, as Ted Whitehead points out in the comments. Not a problem with SVGs as such.

Comment: Did you try to add `pointer-events: none;` to SVG?

Comment: Are you running that code in the browser console on that page? If so, it won’t work on the SVGs because they’re inside of iframes.

Comment: Yes I was just having a first look at SVGs in the console. So they are always nested in iframes which don't appear in the dom when you inspect using the console? That's good to know, if a bit obtuse...

Comment: @Tom take a look at this [example](https://jsbin.com/cubuza/edit?html,js,console,output), when you click any element you got a message on the console. Javascript and jQuery they both can recognize and handle any SVG element.

Comment: Hi thanks for the example. That is what I would expect. And indeed the code I was using also works on http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_inhtml.asp. The only difference I can see between the two sites is this in the svg tag in the one that does not work: `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg".
         <circle id="redcircle" cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="red"></circle>
      </svg>

Comment: did you try using preventDefaults and stopPropogation?

Comment: No I'll have a look at that.

Comment: And Ted, sorry about the dumb response to you. I completely missed the iframes above.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("iframe").contents().find("#svgMain").on("mousedown", function(e){console.log(e)})
```

Comment: Nope. Nice try though. Have a go on http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_svg.html

Comment: I did :).  Anyways, stuff in iframe are treated differently hence the call to .contents().  From there you can do your normal stuff.  BTW that page 404s now.